# Field extensions that decompose into towers of degree$\leq n$ extensions

Tags: reference-request, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field and let $n$ be a natural number.  Consider the class of field extensions $E/F$ that decompose into towers $E=E_k/E_{k-1}/\cdots/E_1/E_0=F$ such that $[E_{i+1}:E_i]\leq n$ for $i=0,1,\ldots n-1$.

I know that if $n\leq 4$, then all such extensions are radical.  But otherwise, I'm not sure what I can say about them.  Do these have a name?  Do you know any basic properties of them?  Can you say something about the Galois group of their Galois closure?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense without any further hypothesis. Is E/F Galois ? How about the successive subextensions ? Etc.

Comment: Why not?  You could assume that $E/F$ and the successive subextensions are Galois if you want, because I think if you replaced them with their Galois closures the resulting extension would still be in the same class.

Comment: Proof: Given the field extension $E_1/F$, take the Galois conjugates of $E_1$ as $E_1^1,\ldots E_1^s$.  Then each subextension in the tower $E_1E_1^1\cdots E_1^s/E_1E_1^1\cdots E_1^{s-1}/\cdots/E_1/F$ is of degree $\leq n$.  Thus the Galois closure $E'_1=E_1E_1^1\cdots E_1^s$ of $E_1$ is in the class.  Similarly decompose the Galois closure $E'_{i+1}/E'_i$ of $E'_iE_{i+1}/E'_i$ to show that it belongs to the class.  Concatenating these towers shows that the extension $E'=E'_k/F$ is in the class.  Now decompose the Galois closure $E'E'^1\cdots E'^l/F$

Comment: (continued) of $E'/F$ (where $E'^1\ldots E'^l$ are Galois conjugates of $E'$) into the tower $E'E'^1\cdots E'^l/E'E'^1\cdots E'^{l-1}/\cdots/E'/F$.  Each subextension in this tower can be decomposed into a tower with subextensions of degree $\leq n$, so the entire tower can.

Comment: Well, if you don't impose any condition on your tower, there is not much to say. You can of course take normal closures, but then you don't control any longer the degrees. For the sake of discussion, take E/F to be Galois, with group G. In principle, the knowledge of G gives you all informations you want on the subextensions. But I guess this is not your question. Since you allude to the resolution of polynomial equations by radicals: if all the intermediate extensions E_i+1/E_i are abelian, your G is  a solvable group. But this is classical. Your question is really not precise enough.